# Не работает открытие комментариев со страницы выборов из уведомлений

Tags: дефект, выборы, навигация

Если попробовать перейти из уведомлений на комментарий, который был оставлен на [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3), то будет открыта просто эта страница, не будет перехода на сам комментарий.

Comment: Что интересно, там у комментариев и ссылок нет

Comment: [tag:так-задумано] :-)

Comment: @Grundy нет https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28815/676433

Comment: В Chrome под iOS у меня работают. А в Android и на винде - нет.